# Data binding with XML views or Controller, Which is recommended in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, data-binding, sapui5

Question is related to basic definition of MVC architecture & data binding, UI5 follows MVC where view is what we want to display and Controller is where the binding done with View & Model. 
in UI5 if you see any standard (old) applications we can see the data binding done at controller level only - Applications with JS views / XML views
we create UI Control in controller and binddata or refer a existing UI control ans bind data
eg:

```
// create your controls        
var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView("textView", {
    // bind text property of textview to firstName property in the model
    text: "{/firstName}",
    tooltip: "First Name"
});
var oTxt = new sap.ui.commons.TextField("txtField", {
    // bind text property of textfield to firstName property in the model
    value: "{/firstName}"
});
```

or

```
var oTXt= this.getView().getElementbyId("text UI id here");
oTxt.bindProperty("enabled", "/enabled");
```

But if you develop any template based application through webIDE or all new applications, we can see the databinding done at XML View level only.
like

```
 <Input value="{/firstName}" valueLiveUpdate="true" width="200px" enabled="{/enabled}" />
      <Label text="Last Name" class="sapUiSmallMargin" />
      <Input value="{/lastName}" valueLiveUpdate="true" width="200px" enabled="{/enabled}" />
      <CheckBox selected="{/enabled}" text="Enabled" />
```

So what is the best approach to follow in data binding and how it supports the definition of MVC in both cases

Thanks,

Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Data binding via the controller is the "old" way of doing data binding. With XML Views it's a lot easier and quicker to do data binding, because the framework does a lot for you.

Your controller coding will get much more readable, because you don't have to bind all the data to your controls.

I would suggest you to use data binding via the view, as long as it fits to your needs. There could be some cases, which require to do the data binding via the controller. However, both ways are correct. Some very strict MVC definition would have a little problem with this, but in my opinion the benefit of this technique is more important than the strict MVC definition.